# Access SQL update a field with the value that subtracted two fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a function at the end of the program that summed the numbers. I'm trying to subtract the `GrandPrice` with another field called `Discount`.

```
UPDATE INV_Headers SET
    GrandTotal = GrandTotal - Discount,
WHERE DocID = "xxxx"
```

But the error message (`Syntax error in UPDATE statement access`) just popped-up, how do I update a field by subtracting the field with another?

---

***EDIT***: This question is due to a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove comma`,`, if you want to update two column then use that comma `,` :

```
UPDATE INV_Headers 
     SET GrandTotal = GrandTotal - Discount
WHERE DocID = "xxxx"
```